# DataGridView, DataTable, SqlDataAdapter and SqlCommandBuilder - disable deletes

Tags: .net, winforms, data-binding, datagridview, sqldataadapter

I have a WinForm that has a DataGridView table. It is bound to a DataTable in conjunction with a SqlDataAdapter and SqlCommandBuilder. What is the best way (easy and easy to manage) of disabling Deletes but allowing Selects, Updates, Inserts?

Is there a one line property I can set on the grid? That is how I would prefer to do it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Probably the easiest thing to do is to look over the properties on your DataGridView and change the AllowUserToDeleteRow to false.

Comment: How do you remove the delete command? The only way I can delete now is selecting the Row and hitting the "delete" keyboard button.

Comment: I updated the answer a bit with the specific way of handling this.

Comment: +1 sweet thanks. By the way, is the "delete" key on the keyboard the only method supported of deleting... or did I miss something?

Comment: I think in this example it is the only way of doing it.  I tend to do more web forms vs. win forms programming and its a little different...